# S/MIME signed e-mail, CRL ?

Tags: crl

Are CRL lookups performed when receiving a S/MIME signed e-mail or onyl when it's encrypted  ?

Answer (score 2):

A Certificate Revocation List (CRL) serves to check that the **Public Key** of an entity, even if signed by a legitimate, recognised Certification Authority (CA), has not ben revoked since it was issued.

A Public Key is used (and thus the CRL is checked) in two occasions:

a. When you want to encrypt an outgoing email you use the Public Key of the recipient
 b. When an incoming message has a digital signature and you check its sender identity based on the validity of the public key of the sender

Please note that to avoid generation of excessive traffic the CRLs are checked periodically and cached in between checks.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, it depends on the S/MIME software you are using. 
Normally, when signing, the software doesn't make any lookup at CRL...it's supposed that you are using a valid certificate for it.

The email recipient (and thus his mail software) is the one responsible for check the email signature (if you only encrypt and **not sign** the email, there is no reason for check the certificate status).

As stated by Georgios, normally, the CRLs are cached ( I really don't know if softwares like Thunderbird or Microsoft Outlook do it ) and checked periodically. Some CAs also have the OCSP responder for check certificates status, but again, it depends on your mail software.

[]'s